# Wpf button click in xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently working on the following code.

```
public void CbParty_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        spPartijen.Children.Clear();
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=imtenb; Uid=root; Pwd=");
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM kandidaten WHERE partij='" + ((DataRowView)cbParty.SelectedItem)["naam"].ToString() + "' ";
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
        dtData.Load(reader);

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        da.Fill(dtData);


        foreach (DataRow dr in dtData.Rows)
        {
            TextBox tbId = new TextBox();
            tbId.Text = dr["id"].ToString();
            tbId.Name = "tbId";

            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Text = dr["kandidaat"].ToString();
            tb.Name = "tb";

            Button button = new Button();
            button.Content = "wijzigen";
            button.Click += ChangeKandidaat_Click;

            spPartijen.Children.Add(tb);
            spPartijen.Children.Add(button);
        }
    }

    public void ChangeKandidaat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        conn.ChangeKandidaat(tbId.Text, tb.Text, ((DataRowView)cbParty.SelectedItem)["naam"].ToString());
    }


public void ChangeKandidaat(string id, string kandidaat, string partij)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE kandidaten SET kandidaat='kandiddddaat' WHERE partij='@partij' and id='@id'";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kandidaat", kandidaat);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partij", partij);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("De informatie is succesvol gewijzigd");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Er is iets mis gegaan met het toevoegen van je standpunt, probeer het opnieuw.");
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

My problem is that the ChangeKandidaat_Click cannot see the tbId.Text and tb.Text, because is isn't maked yet.

Maybe someone has a solution for me. Or am I doing this kind of thing wrong.
I'm pretty new to wpf and C#.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into MVVM and WPF's templating system.

When you have UI with repetition then you should be thinking of an itemscontrol. Bind the itemssource to a List or observablecollection where t is a viewmodel. That would have public properties for each attribute in the thing you're repeating. Then associate the template with t via datatype or just using the itemtemplate property of the itemscontrol.

Let's call t a row viewmodel or rowvm.
That would expose a public icommand property. Bind that to the command of your button and when you click a button, the code you have in the command fires. That "knows" the associated value of Kandidaat because it would be a public property in the rowvm and hence this.Kandidaat.

Itemscontrol:

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/

Instead of just a button you could have a bunch of stuff defined per "row":

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                …..
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Kandidaat}" 
                        Grid.Column="1"/>
             <Button
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Content="DoSomething" 
                   Command="{DoSomethingCommand}" />
        </Grid>

    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Simple intro to mvvm and itemscontrol:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx

That's just using a string as a rowvm, you would want a class with Id, Kandidaat and command properties.

Some simple to complicated examples:

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1160/wpf-itemscontrol-fundamentals-part1

In order to line the columns of id, kandidaat and buttons up you could use a grid with columns and shared size scope.
https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/issharedsizescope/

Or

You could use a gridview in a listview, which has columns built in.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listview?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does not show exactly the whole problem.  Would be nice to know is this WPF?  Windows Forms?

I assume that spParijen is a table or grid which is populated with the tb and button data. These are the initial things I see are wrong and it is all dealing with context:

tbId, tb, and button are populated within the context of the foreach loop.  If that collection was later displayed I'd imagine you'd see an empty list.  That is because each object created within the context of that foreach loop gets destroyed once you leave the loop or shortly after creating a new instance or very shortly after.  The only reason your button does not get destroyed is because you have a binding to your click delegate code.

The second issue is the name of your three variables.  They don't tell the next developer what these fields actually represent.  I assume that the button represents a chosen candidate so name it as such.

The third problem is that the first variable (tbId) will never exist because it is not saved anywhere.

And finally let's say you have 10 candidates.  So if your code worked you would have a list of 10 candidates and 10 buttons.  So your click handler will fail or (if they weren't destroyed) you would always process the last candidate you put in the list.  You need the button to contain something unique so that you can find the Content of the button and thus the list that each textbox is in.

My suggestion is to populate the children with dr["id"], dr[candidate], button.  The click handler logic will first cast sender as a button.  Next get the identifier from the button (you could make the tooltip the identity if you are doing WPF).  Then search your children until you find that ID.  Now continue your process.